# Why glutWireCube() does not display my wire cube?

Tags: opengl, glut

I am novice to OpenGL and I read that `glutWireCube`draws a wire cube. Now that it is not appearing on when I run my code, I am wondering what does it do? Does it draw a cube or where have I gone wrong in my code?

```
  #include<GL/glut.h>
  GLdouble cubeSize= 10.0;
  //FUNCTIONS DECLARATIONS - PROTOTYPES
  void init(void);
  void display(void);

 int main(int argc, char ** argv){
 glutInit(&argc,argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE |GLUT_RGBA);
 glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
 glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
 glutCreateWindow("Wire Cube");
 init();
 glutDisplayFunc(display);

 glutMainLoop();
 }

//FUNCTIONS IMPLEMENTAION - DEFINITION

void init(void){
     glClearColor(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     }

void display(void){
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
     glutWireCube(5.0);
     glEnd();
     glFlush();
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `glutWireCube` is not allowed inside a `glBegin`/`glEnd` block. Only `glVertex` to specify vertices and all the functions to set the current values of some vertex attributes (like `glNormal`, `glColor`, ...) can be used there.

How `glutWireCube` internally works is not specified. It might as well use immediate mode, but in this case, it will do its own `glBegin`/`glEnd` calls.

Conceptually, trying to put a cube into a `GL_POLYGON` is also not going to work. `GL_POLYGON` is for drawing a *single*, *flat*, *convex* polygon, and it is totally impossible to draw a whole cube as one polygon.

Furthermore, you do not set up any of the `GL_MODELVIEW` or `GL_PROJECTION` matrices. This means you directly draw in clip space, and `glutWireCube` with size 5 will draw a cube which completely lies outside of your viewing frustum, so you will see nothing.

Comment: Well, a good explanation indeed and you have touched concepts that were confusing me a lot. One thing: Is it that I must set `GL_MODEVIEW` followed by `GL_PROJECTION` matrices so that the cube can drawn properly?